# Como puedo obtener el valor o value de un select

Tags: select

Quiero seleccionar varias options pero a la hora de recorrer me imprime solo un valor options

```
//  var cod = document.getElementById("Defectos").value;

//para obtener vor de select
var combo = document.getElementById("Defectos");
var selected = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text;

let array = {
    salid: selected
    
    
    };
    
for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(array)){
     console.log(value)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Según comprendo, tienes un select múltiple y quieres obtener todas las opciones seleccionadas. Partiendo de esto, un ejemplo con frutas:

HTML

```
<select id="frutas" multiple>
   <option value="naranja">Naranja</option>
   <option value="manzana">Manzana</option>
   <option value="pera">Pera</option>
   <option value="mango">Mango</option>
</select>
    
<button type="button" id="mostrar">Mostrar</button>
```

En **opcionesCombo** convertimos la [lista de nodos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NodeList) del select **frutasCombo** en un arreglo usando [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). Gracias a esto, podremos utilizar el método [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) y recorrer el arreglo hasta reducirlo a un único valor.

Dentro de cada iteración revisaremos si la opción actual ha sido seleccionada, y de ser el caso, haremos [.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) de su valor en el arreglo vacío que es nuestro acumulador. Este acumulador contendrá todos los valores de las opciones que fueron seleccionadas, y será el resultado final almacenado en la variable **frutasSeleccionadas**.

JS (ES6+)

```
const mostrarBtn = document.querySelector('#mostrar');

mostrarBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Select múltiple de frutas
  const frutasCombo = document.querySelector('#frutas');

  // Convertimos lista de nodos de opciones en un arreglo
  const opcionesCombo = Array.from(frutasCombo.options);

  // Recorremos el arreglo de opciones
  const frutasSeleccionadas = opcionesCombo.reduce((frutasAcumuladas, frutaActual) => {
      // Si la opción (fruta) actual ha sido seleccionada
      if (frutaActual.selected) {
        // Añadimos su valor al arreglo acumulador de reduce **
        frutasAcumuladas.push(frutaActual.value);
      }

      // Retornamos las frutas acumuladas
      return frutasAcumuladas;

  }, []); // El valor inicial de frutasAcumuladas será un arreglo vacío **

  console.log(frutasSeleccionadas);
});
```

Comment: Gracias justo lo que buscaba